# How do I debug an Atompub POST sent via cURL to Wordpress on XP + Apache 2.2 + XDebug

Tags: php, netbeans, curl, xdebug

I've been using NetBeans as the XDebug interactive debugging client. But seems like it only supports attaching debuggers to scripts that are invoked via Firefox. I want to step through the request parse script when it's invoked via cURL.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer. First I attached a debugger by right-clicking on the wordpress project in netbeans and choosing "debug". This will open the blog in firefox with the "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug" param included in the url (e.g. "http://localhost/wordpress/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug").

Then I invoked cURL from the command line, making sure to set a cookie with the name/value XDEBUG_SESSION/netbeans-xdebug:

```
>curl "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-app.php/posts" -X POST -H "Content-type: application/atom+xml" -v -L -k -u admin:password --data @post_atom_entry_bad.xml -o post_bad_response.txt -b XDEBUG_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /wordpress/wp-app.php/posts HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46d2Fuc3Vp
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.1 (i586-pc-mingw32msvc) libcurl/7.19.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8i zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug
> Content-type: application/atom+xml
> Content-Length: 302
>
} [data not shown]
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   302    0     0    0   302      0     74 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
```

At this point cURL halts at the breakpoint I have set at line 283 in wp-app.php, AtomParser->handle_request(), and I can step through the code.

Once I click F5 (continue), the server sends the response back to cURL:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   302    0     0    0   302      0      2 --:--:--  0:02:17 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 15 Dec 2008 17:47:06 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.6
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain
<
100   302    0     0    0   302      0      2 --:--:--  0:02:18 --:--:--     0* Closing connection #0


>
```

Done. Would be great to get examples from other interactive debugging clients like notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Related XDebug docs: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session